# C# override Entity Framework Database.ExecuteSqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is there a way for me to override Database.ExecuteSqlCommand so that I can force a stored procedure to run (along with whatever the actual sql is) every time I call it?

Comment: What do you mean by *"so that I can force a stored procedure to run (along with whatever the actual sql is) every time I call it"*? Can you show us what your SQL is?

Comment: I believe it means to run a SP before executing Raw SQL code with ExecuteSqlCommand

Comment: I doubt that it is possible. `Database` Property of `DbContext` doesn't have setter, so you can't  replace `Database` instance with your implementation.

Comment: you can pretty easily override the `SaveChanges` method but this will only help you run a sproc on create/update/delete, not retrieving data. I can provide an example if you think this would get you where you need to be

Comment: What version of EF?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#interception-of-database-operations and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception

Comment: Alexander is correct, I have a stored procedure that I want to be executed every time ExecuteSqlCommand is called.  Searching for a while made me think it was impossible, I just wanted to confirm.

Comment: EF version:  Version=6.0.0.0

Comment: Is this a surreptitious interception of the `ExecuteSqlCommand` method, or could you simply provide a different method for your other developers to call?  Note that there are other ways to execute bare SQL against an EF instance.

Comment: I could provide a different method yes, it is slightly more work and I wanted to confirm that I couldn't just override and tack on my SP.

Comment: *shrug*.  The method isn't virtual.

Comment: I suppose you could try Code Weaving or some other form of AOP.

Comment: At this point I think I will just provide a different method, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot override `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` because those methods are not virtual. Also, usually it's not a good idea to call `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` directly from services/controllers. Instead you could have another level of abstraction where you could have method which will call stored procedure before executing SQL command.

```
    public int RunSqlCommand(string sql, params object[] parameters)
    {
        _database.ExecuteSqlCommand("YourStoredProcedure @p0", parameters: new[] {"Parameter1"});
        _database.ExecuteSqlCommand (sql, parameters);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't. At least not through overriding.
[For you to override a method it has to originally be abstract or virtual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override).

You can create a method in your DbContext class to deal with the execution of your stored procedure before executing your query instead.

Comment: Are you talking about adding an extension method?

Comment: It could be, but an extension would only be used to prepare a query (attaching SP there). I was talking about creating a full method in a Context class.

Answer (score 0):

What I eventually went with to have the least minimal impact to existing code was to just use the connection interceptor.  Whenever a connection is opened I ran my stored procedure before anything else:

`public class myInterceptor : IDbConnectionInterceptor
{
        public void Opened(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
        {
        //do my SP here
        }
}`

Answer (score -1):

A few ideas that come into my mind would be to implement your own method (override or extend Database), to 'force' the execution of the stored procedure before and then, run the SQL that was passed as a parameter.
Some other option would be to use Dapper and call your procedure and then your SQL.

Comment: How do you propose to override a non-virtual method?